# How to get a response of BatchWriteItem DocumentClient?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm going to put an item in two dynamodb tables. This is my request params of BatchWriteItem operation.

```
RequestItems: {
    first_table: [{
        PutRequest: {
            Item: {
                employee_id: '123',
                company_id: '123',
                job_position: 'manager'
            }
        }
    }],
    second_table: [{
        PutRequest: {
            Item: {
                facility_id: '123',
                company_id: '123',
                job_position: 'manager'
            }
        }
    }]
},
ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL"
```

My item is updated succefully but I get this response -

> UnprocessedItems: {}

How can I get response with updated data? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to get a response containing the items you have put using [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#API_BatchWriteItem_RequestSyntax). [PutItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) can return overwritten values, but not new ones.

You might consider:

1) Using the data you already have. Afterall, you know the items have been written and you already have them.

2) If you want some statistics on your batchwrite you could use

```
"ReturnItemCollectionMetrics": "SIZE"
```

3) Query for the items after you have written them.